# How do I pick right TextBox to input value in it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Need help in achieving functionality for the image that I insert.

I have 4-5 textboxes and near them some type of calculator.
All TextBoxes are bound to properties in ViewModel.
All calculator buttons use `Command="{Binding AddNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="9"` for passing value to a property.
Problem is that I don't know how to pick the right TextBox for inputting value.

Thanks for the advice.
[image: 1]

Comment: So basically, you want your input focus to remain within an arbitrary textbox while pressing the calculator buttons and you want to produce some sort of textbox input programmatically based on the button pressed handler?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways I could think of to do this. Note that whichever way you do it, I'm pretty sure you'll have to set `Focusable` to `false` on all your `Button`s, otherwise they'll steal the focus away from the `TextBox`es when clicked.

## Keyboard Focus Events

You could declare a field where you track the currently focused `TextBox` (e.g. `private TextBox focusedBox;`). And for each `TextBox`, you could handle the [`GotKeyboardFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.gotkeyboardfocus) and [`LostKeyboardFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.lostkeyboardfocus) events. You could use those events to track which `TextBox` currently has focus, and when you want to add a number you just add it to `focusedBox`.

You would also have to check if `focusedBox` is `null`, in case none of your `TextBox`es are currently focused.

This method would ensure that the calculator buttons only ever effect those `TextBox`es you want them to.

## Keyboard.FocusedElement

Alternatively, you could just use the [`Keyboard.FocusedElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.focusedelement) static property. This will point to whatever element currently has keyboard focus. This coud be any focusable element in your application, or `null` if the keyboard focus is outside your application.

You could attempt to cast `Keyboard.FocusedElement` to `TextBox`, and if the cast succeeds, append the text.

This would require much less code, but also allows the buttons to add text to *any* `TextBox` in your application. This may or may not be a problem, and could be prevented by setting some unique property on the `TextBox`es you want to allow input on and checking for it, or keeping a list of said `TextBox`es.